# sql query to replace city pune to mumbai and mumbai to pune in the table

Tags: mysql, sql

i have one table emp with column  name city

```
city                         output table
-----
mumbai                           pune
pune                             mumbai
mumbai                           pune
pune                             mumbai
pune                             mumbai
```

i want update query to replace pune to mumbai and mumbai to pune

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a query:

```
select (case when city = 'mumbai' then 'pune'
             when city = 'pune' then 'mumbai'
             else city
        end)
. . .
```

If you want to change the values, then:

```
update table t
     set city = (case when city = 'mumbai' then 'pune'
                      when city = 'pune' then 'mumbai'
                 end)
     where city in ('mumbai', 'pune');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the below:

```
UPDATE TABLENAME
SET city= (
CASE 

WHEN city = 'mumbai'
THEN 'pune'

WHEN city = 'pune'
THEN 'mumbai'

END )
```

Hope it helps.