# update query by decode

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle11g

i have one city table .in which i have to replace indore with pune and pune with indore

```
city                             output table
-----                            ------------
indore                            pune
pune                              indore
indore                            pune 
pune                              indore
indore                            pune
```

Comment: why do you have two different RDBMSes tagged?

Comment: because i want solution in both RDBMS

Comment: possible duplicate of [sql query to replace city pune to mumbai and mumbai to pune in the table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26673629/sql-query-to-replace-city-pune-to-mumbai-and-mumbai-to-pune-in-the-table)

Comment: i have to replace indore to mumbai and mumbai to indore

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways,`DECODE` or `CASE` expression.

1.Using `DECODE`

`select decode(city, 'indore', 'pune', 'pune', 'indore', city) from table`

2.Using `CASE`

```
select case 
               when city = 'indore' 
                   then 'pune'
               when city = 'pune' 
                   then 'indore'
               else city
            end
```

I don't understand what you mean by replace. Do you want to do an `update` or just want to display this way? Anyway, if you want to display, the query will work perfectly. To update, you need to convert it into update statement.

**EDIT** On OP's new request.

**You cant use decode in an update statement. However, you can use `MERGE` statement.**

```
MERGE INTO table a
USING (
select city, decode(city, 'indore', 'pune', 'pune', 'indore', city) city_decode
   from table) b
ON (a.city = b.city)
   WHEN MATCHED 
   THEN
      UPDATE SET a.city = b.city_decode
/
```

Comment: i want to update table .
how to use decode with udate

Comment: Use `MERGE` statement. See my answer.